# Scanf skipping a line

Tags: c, arrays, loops, printf, scanf

I'm writing a code that prompts a user to enter the highs and lows for a number of days (between 3 - 10) of their choosing. So far everything is coming out right with the exception of the scanf function for entering the high and low temperatures appearing one line lower than they should be. For instance Day 1 High and Low will be output, but the input for the user begins at Day 1 Low, so the input for High is next to low and the input for Low is on the next blank line.

I figure the issue may be that printf is finishing it's function of outputting both the high and low before scanf takes effect. Is there any way to have scanf occur so that the high and low values can be entered next to one another?  Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i;
    int limit;
    int day[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int high[10],low[10];

    printf("---===IPC Temperature Analyzer V2.0===---\n");

    printf("Please enter the number of days between 3 and 10, inclusive: ");
    scanf("%d", &limit);
    while (limit <= 2 || limit >= 11) {
            printf("Invalid");
            scanf("%d", &limit);
    }

    for(i = 0;i < limit; i++) {
            printf("Day %d - High:\n Day %d - Low: ",day[i],day[i]);
            scanf("%d%d", &high[i], &low[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the cursor on the screen will be at the end of the last printout, so what you saw is how it works.  you may ask user to enter high and low separately, such as printf("Day %d - Hight: ", day[i]);scanf("%d", &high[i]);printf("Day %d - Low: ", day[i]);scanf("%d", &low[i]);

Comment: The `\n` in the prompt moved you to the next line. How can the system be magically expected to realise you want the cursor to move up a line? Print the prompt for the first entry, get its input, then the prompt for the second entry, and get its input.

Comment: I applied your suggestion Wasi and it's working as intended now, thanks! I had tried this method initially, but I believe my code had other errors within it at the time, which caused it to output all the highs and then all the lows.

Comment: Note that the array `day` is not really needed.  You could print `i+1` in the prompt instead of using `day[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
for(i = 0;i < limit; i++) {
    printf("Day %d - High: ", day[i]);
    scanf("%d", &high[i]);
    printf("Day %d - Low: ", day[i]);
    scanf("%d", &low[i]);
}
```

This results in:

```
Please enter the number of days between 3 and 10, inclusive: 4
Day 1 - High: 5
Day 1 - Low: 3
Day 2 - High: 4
Day 2 - Low: 2
Day 3 - High: 2
Day 3 - Low: 1
Day 4 - High: 5
Day 4 - Low: 9
```